# Can't get :valid to work with textarea or input type="number"

Tags: css, transition

First-time poster, so I apologize in advance if I'm omitting anything or not following accepted posting protocol. :)  Any suggestions are welcome!

I'm having some trouble getting a CSS transition effect to work on parts of a form - specifically a textarea and two number fields. As you'll see in the demo code, when a user clicks on a form element, the label is meant to shrink and move upwards, out of the way of the text being entered. It stays there if something is entered, and returns to its normal location if the user moves on or doesn't enter something. The :focus and :valid pseudo-classes work on most elements, so I'm sure there's something I'm not understanding about the textarea and number element validity.

This is my transition code:

```
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label, textarea:focus ~ label, select:focus ~ label, select:valid ~ label {
font-size: 0.75em;
color: #fff;
top: -5px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.225s ease;
transition: all 0.225s ease;
```

}

...but adding *textarea:valid ~ label* does not have the intended effect. Also, *numbers* is already covered in that code via *input*, but it doesn't have the intended effect either.

I didn't bother pasting the form in its entirety - but please compare the properly-functioning effect from the *First and Last Name* and *Country* fields with the fields below.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/mgabe/pen/LYmdOKj)

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: hello, the required attribute is missing and the selector textarea:valid ~ label, is also missing . Is that it ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is that those fields are not required. The textarea is for optional comments, and the two number fields are for Adult and Child hats. Someone may want one size but not the other. 

As for the textarea:valid selector, I had to remove it, as it pins the label to the top of the texrarea permanently. In essence, those number fields and the textarea are in a ‘valid’ state perpetually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #E9CDE4;
  background-image: url("assets/logo_back.jpg");
  background-size: repeat-x repeat-y;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.styled-input {
  float: left;
  width: 318px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.styled-input.wide {
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.styled-input label {
  color: #666;
  padding: 1.3rem 30px 1rem 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #E9CDE4;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: #D0A2CA;
}

input:not([type="number"]):focus~label,
input:not([type="number"]):valid~label,
textarea:focus~label,
textarea:not([data-val=""])~label,
select:focus~label,
select:valid~label {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #fff;
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.225s ease;
  transition: all 0.225s ease;
}

input[type="number"]:focus~label,
input[type="number"]:not([value=""])~label {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #fff;
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.225s ease;
  transition: all 0.225s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="styled-input wide">
        <textarea name="form_comments" data-val="" onkeyup="(()=>{this.dataset.val=this.value})()"></textarea>
        <label>Additional instructions or comments (optional)</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <divhttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/73905218/edit# class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="styled-input">
        <input class="number" name="form_adultnum" type="number" min="0" onchange="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" />
        <label>Adult Beanies</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

To use the `:valid` of a `<textarea>` element, you have to set some extra value e.g. `minlength`, `maxlength`, or `required`. [textarea element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#styling_valid_and_invalid_values)

If you still want to keep the attribute, you can look into my code. I add a little bit of 'javascript' code into the textarea to catch the `keyup` event.

`<textarea name="form_comments" data-val="" onkeyup="(()=>{this.dataset.val=this.value})()"></textarea>`

And then use the CSS selector to select all `textarea` which value is empty `textarea:not([data-val=""])~label`

### Update

I add modification to `input[type="number"]`, additional you can use the attribute `value` instead of the `data-val`. With this type of input I have to separated it to another css block for easy modification

Comment: Bao - thanks for your help! It works perfectly for the textarea field. Just as an aside, the reason I couldn't run with the 'required' attribute (defeats the purpose of 'optional comments') :) and the min length didn't seem to have the effect I needed. But your Javascript worked perfectly.

Comment: May I follow up by asking how I would modify that code for the number elements above the textarea? I tried modifying your solution to fit, but it doesn't have the same effect. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello @MichaelGabe, I've just modified my answer to add the solution for the input.

Comment: Hi Bao - realized I hadn't thanked you for the modification. Again, much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I used some javascript to make it works. I'm using inline javascript. You may want to detach it and use it as a separate function instead. You can read more about it here [JS Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)